# Magento SQL Error when trying to add description programmaticaly

Tags: php, sql, magento

I'm trying to add parsed data to each product's description.

That's what I have:

```
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$productMage = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

foreach ($productDescXpath as $description) { // Find each item's description
    if (!$productMage->load($dataId)->getData('description')) {
        $productMage->load($dataId)->getData('description');
        $productMage->setDescription($description->nodeValue);
        $productMage->save();
    }
}
```

In $dataId I have each product's ID and in $description->nodeValue those description.

If I'm trying to use it only with one product(e.g replace $dataID with really product ID, for example 570) and add some string instead of $description->nodeValue - it works.

But if I'm using first construction - that's what I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update 
a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`semenin_magento`.`
catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT 
`FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY 
(`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id)' in 
/home/s/semenin/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228                                                                                                                                                                                          

 Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 #0 /home/s/semenin/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)                                                                                                                      
 #1 /home/s/semenin/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)          
 #2/home/s/semenin/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300):Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)          
 #3 /home/s/semenin/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)                                                                                                              
 #4 /home/s/semenin/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)                                                                              
 #5 /home/s/semenin/publi in /home/s/semenin/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 234
```

Comment: Can you give us the log of $dataId and $description variables?

Comment: @Jouby, Hi. Of course - it's bit of  $dataId =    19523 19524 19522 19511 19509 19508 19496 and in $description some text for each $dataId, it's a big for this comment, but it's exist.

Comment: Hm... Items with this Id's doesn't exist in 'catalog_product_entity' table

Comment: Ok, And how I can update the description by known product's name? For example, I have "iPhone 7" product, I can do it with this? $productMage->getName('iPhone 7')->setDescription('test description')->save();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, if your $dataId is **an array** or not. If not, just use `$dataId = explode(' ', $dataId)`.

To only change description, you don't need to load your product. **Load a product is really expensive**, and you have to use it carefully. Try to use `saveAttribute` of catalog/product resource model:

```
foreach ($dataId as $productId) {
    $attributeCode = 'description';
    $data = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $data->setData($attributeCode, $description->nodeValue);
    $data->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $data->setId($productId);
    $data->isObjectNew(false);

    Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->saveAttribute($data, $attributeCode);
}
```

In Magento, it's **totally forbidden to do a load in a foreach**. If you wan't to load many entities, **use Magento collections**.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, could you help me please, How I can add description by product's Name(not ID) ?

Comment: You have to use a collection and filter by name.